# Script returning unwanted output

Tags: bash, shell-script

Here's what I currently have (top bash window) and the result the syntax returns (bottom bash window).

When a name does not exist, such as "xyz" it returns the appropriate response.

When a name does exist, such as "joel" it echos an unwanted response before providing the correct response..

What am I missing?

```bash
name=$1
OUTPUT=$(grep -i $name ~uli101/2016c/phonebook)

if [ "$name" = "" ]

then echo -n "Enter a name to search for: "

        read name

fi



if [ $? -ne 1 ]

then echo "Name $name not in directory"

fi

grep -i $name ~uli101/2016c/phonebook
~
```

```
:~/scripts> phone4 xyz
Name xyz not in directory
:~/scripts> phone4 joel
Name joel not in directory
SHAPRIO JOEL                SH      4802   BUSINESS STUDIES DIVISION
:~/scripts>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script reports that the name isn't found, then reports that the name exists.  This is because of your condition `if [ $? -ne 1 ]`.  The "$?" represents the return code of the last expression in the script.  In this case it is the return code of the previous 'if' block.

To get your desired results, move the 'grep' command between the first and second 'if' blocks.  This way the second 'if' will evaluate the results of the grep.  If grep finds a result it will print that result and it's return code will be 0 and the block will be skipped.  If grep does not find a result it should print nothing and it's return code will be 1, causing the conditional to be executed.

Answer (score -2):

Not all versions of *grep* know about *-q*
A little trick I use - when I am only interested in the status of a command is to prefix the command with 'nohup' - because I am lazy and forget the "redirection way"

**nohup way**

```
nohup grep -i string_arg file_args >/dev/null
status=$?
```

**redirection way**

```
grep -i string_arg file_args  2>&1 >/dev/null
status=$?
```

Comment: Pretty certain the 'unwanted output' he's referring to is the 'not in directory' response.  He says 'echos an unwanted response before the appropriate response' thus the grep output is wanted and the preceding line is unwanted.

Comment: Quite correct - I was blinded by an earlier 'answer', that seems now deleted, that had grep -q as an answer. I suppose I should delete my answer - as I missed the logic error you saw. Ouch for my ability to get to 50 :p @ me